# Random with button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got code where you enter some text and pressing #val makes the text be shown as a paragraphs. 
Then i got another button with `id="#kor"` and when pressing it i want the computer to random choose between all these paragraphs.

I have come this far :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#val').click(function() {
    var toAdd = $("input[name=message]").val();
    $('#messages').append("<p>"+toAdd+"</p>");
});
$('#kor').click(function() {
    var random = Math.floor((Math.random()*10);
    $("p").eq(random).click();

});
});
```

Comment: Why `*10`? It should be `*$("#messages>p").length`, and you should use `$("#messages>p").eq(random).click()` to trigger the click.

Comment: You mean $("#messages>p").eq(random).click() instead of : var random = Math.floor((Math.random()*10); 

and *$("#messages>p").length where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#kor').click(function() {
    var paragraphs = $('#messages>p'),
        random = Math.floor(Math.random() * paragraphs.length);
    paragraphs.eq(random).click();
});
```

This prevents it from nuking "all" `<p>` elements on your page, by only looking for ones that are in your `#messages` element. Furthermore, it actually counts them to see what range the random number should be in.

Of course, this assumes that `.click()` on the paragraphs actually does something.